# About Python Flask "BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'index'. Did you mean 'main.index' instead?"

Tags: python, flask

In my limited experience with Python programing and I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

The error messages:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Flask\Sample\venv\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1488, in _execute
    result = self.prepare()
  File "G:\Flask\Sample\venv\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 2774, in prepare
    self.fallback(self.request)
  File "G:\Flask\Sample\venv\lib\site-packages\livereload\server.py", line 89, in __call__
    WSGIContainer.environ(request), start_response)
  File "G:\Flask\Sample\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "G:\Flask\Sample\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "G:\Flask\Sample\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "G:\Flask\Sample\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "G:\Flask\Sample\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "G:\Flask\Sample\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "G:\Flask\Sample\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "G:\Flask\Sample\app\main\views.py", line 7, in index
    return render_template('index.html', title='Welcome')
  File "G:\Flask\Sample\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 134, in render_template
    context, ctx.app)
  File "G:\Flask\Sample\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 116, in _render
    rv = template.render(context)
  File "G:\Flask\Sample\venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 1008, in render
    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
  File "G:\Flask\Sample\venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 780, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "G:\Flask\Sample\app\templates\index.html", line 2, in top-level template code
    {% import '_macro.html' as ma %}
  File "G:\Flask\Sample\app\templates\base.html", line 1, in top-level template code
    {% extends 'bootstrap/base.html' %}
  File "G:\Flask\Sample\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_bootstrap\templates\bootstrap\base.html", line 1, in top-level template code
    {% block doc -%}
  File "G:\Flask\Sample\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_bootstrap\templates\bootstrap\base.html", line 4, in block "doc"
    {%- block html %}
  File "G:\Flask\Sample\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_bootstrap\templates\bootstrap\base.html", line 20, in block "html"
    {% block body -%}
  File "G:\Flask\Sample\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_bootstrap\templates\bootstrap\base.html", line 21, in block "body"
    {% block navbar %}
  File "G:\Flask\Sample\app\templates\base.html", line 13, in block "navbar"
    {{ nav.top.render() }}
  File "G:\Flask\Sample\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_nav\elements.py", line 24, in render
    self))
  File "G:\Flask\Sample\venv\lib\site-packages\visitor\__init__.py", line 48, in visit
    return meth(node)
  File "G:\Flask\Sample\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_bootstrap\nav.py", line 53, in visit_Navbar
    bar_list.add(self.visit(item))
  File "G:\Flask\Sample\venv\lib\site-packages\visitor\__init__.py", line 48, in visit
    return meth(node)
  File "G:\Flask\Sample\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_bootstrap\nav.py", line 98, in visit_View
    item.add(tags.a(node.text, href=node.get_url(), title=node.text))
  File "G:\Flask\Sample\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_nav\elements.py", line 77, in get_url
    return url_for(self.endpoint, **self.url_for_kwargs)
  File "G:\Flask\Sample\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\helpers.py", line 333, in url_for
    return appctx.app.handle_url_build_error(error, endpoint, values)
  File "G:\Flask\Sample\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1805, in handle_url_build_error
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "G:\Flask\Sample\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\helpers.py", line 323, in url_for
    force_external=external)
  File "G:\Flask\Sample\venv\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\routing.py", line 1768, in build
    raise BuildError(endpoint, values, method, self)
BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'index'. Did you mean 'main.index' instead?
```

This is the directory layout of my project:

```
/Sample
    /app
        /auth
            /__init__.py
            /forms.py
            /views.py
        /main
            /__init__.py
            /views.py
        /templates
            /index.html
            /base.html
            /login.html
        /__init__.py
        /models.py
   /manager.py
   /venv
```

I think my problem is in /main/views.py but I can't find it .

/main/views.py:

```
from flask import render_template, request, redirect, url_for, make_response, flash
from . import main

@main.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', title='Welcome')

@main.route('/services')
def services():
    return render_template('index.html', title='services')

@main.route('/about')
def about():
    return render_template('index.html', title='about')

@main.route('/user/<regex("[a-z]{3}"):user_id>')
def user(user_id):
    return 'User %s' % user_id

@main.route('/work/')
def projects():
    return render_template('index.html', title='projects')

@main.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(error):
    return render_template('404.html'), 404

# @main.template_test('current_link')
# def current_link(link):
#     return link == request.path


def read_md(filename):
    with open(filename) as md_file:
        content = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, md_file.readline())
    return content.decode('utf-8')

@main.context_processor
def inject_methods():
    return dict(read_md=read_md)
```

/main/**init**.py:

```
from flask import Blueprint

main = Blueprint('main', __name__)

from . import views
```

/app/**init**.py:

```
from os import path
from flask import Flask
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask_nav import Nav
from flask_nav.elements import *
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from werkzeug.routing import BaseConverter

class RegexConverter(BaseConverter):
    def __init__(self, url_map, *items):
        super(RegexConverter, self).__init__(url_map)
        self.regex = items[0]

basedir =  path.abspath(path.dirname(__file__))

bootstrap = Bootstrap()
#app.config['BOOTSTRAP_SERVE_LOCAL'] = True
db = SQLAlchemy()
nav = Nav()

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.url_map.converters['regex'] = RegexConverter
    app.config.from_pyfile('config')
    app.config['DEBUG'] = True
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = \
        'sqlite:///' + path.join(basedir, 'data.sqlite')
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_COMMIT_ON_TEARDOWN'] = True
    nav.register_element('top', Navbar('Flask',
                                        View('Index', 'index'),
                                        View('About', 'about'),
                                        View('Services', 'services'),
                                        View('Projects', 'projects')))
    nav.init_app(app)
    bootstrap.init_app(app)
    db.init_app(app)

    from .auth import auth as auth_blueprint
    from .main import main as main_blueprint

    app.register_blueprint(auth_blueprint)
    app.register_blueprint(main_blueprint)

    return app
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is with a call to `url_for('index')`. As your error said, you must use `url_for('main.index')`. If this call is in the same blueprint, you can even make it relative `url_for('.index')`.

It is an easy fix, but in all code you pasted here, you didn't pasted the code with the problem.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me that I have just submitted the error message.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I found the problem where the third parameter of this nav.register_element() function, should use 'main.index' for it.I apologize for my inadvertently ， and thank you for your answer sincerely