# Flask App: Could not build url for endpoint 'post_to_db'

Tags: python, sql, post, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am new to making Flask apps, so I might be missing something obvious. What I am trying to do is take a value from a slider and increment a value in my postgresql table by the slider value and then increment another value in my postgresql table by 1. I am getting the error:

```
werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'post_to_db'. Did you mean 'static' instead?
```

Here is my html:

```html
<form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('post_to_db') }}">
    <input class='slider'id="mydata" name="mydata" type="range" min="0" max="10" value="5" step='1'>
    <div id='button-dock'>
        <button type='submit'>"Show Me Another"</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is my python:

```python
class Dataentry(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "shoe-ratings"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    total_score = db.Column(db.Integer)
    num_ratings = db.Column(db.Integer)

    def __init__(self, total_score, num_ratings):
        self.total_score = total_score
        self.num_ratings = num_ratings

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<id {}>'.format(self.id)

    def serialize(self):
        return {
            'id': self.id,
            'total_score': self.total_score,
            'num_ratings': self.num_ratings
        }

@app.route("/virgil_io/submit/", methods=["POST"])
def post_to_db():

    score = request.form['mydata']

    shoe = Dataentry.query.first()
    shoe.total_score = shoe.c.total_score + score
    shoe.num_ratings = shoe.c.num_ratings + 1

    try:
        db.session.add(shoe)
        db.session.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        print("\n FAILED entry\n")
        print(e)
        sys.stdout.flush()
    return "Success"

@APP.route('/virgil_io/')
def index():
    return flask.render_template('index.html')
```

Here is my directory:

[image]

Things I've tried:

- Creating a /submit folder in my directory.
- Taking out `methods=["POST"]`

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Please also show the code path that gets that HTML template into the browser.

Comment: Possible duplicate. Please refer answer on https://stackoverflow.com/a/44006237/7622397

Comment: @DaveW.Smith I have edited it.

Comment: @JayJodiwal Thank you. I have looked at this and don't think it is the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

As always, it was a stupid little thing. My app was named `APP`, but I was using `app` for this method.